# Are CocoaPods in the specs repo the only official releases?

Tags: cocoapods

I thought the [CocoaPods specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) listed all officially released versions of a project, but we've found vulnerabilities for versions not in the specs repo, like [this](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-12543) which says "Eclipse Mosquitto versions 1.5 to 1.5.2" but the [specs repo only has 1.4.8](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/9543734012238c33ea018af5a4381459c13f0916/Specs/3/d/7/Mosquitto).

I don't know CocoaPods well. **Is it common to use CocoaPods not in the specs repo?**

I know you can depend on [git repo tags](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#specification) so I'm hoping for an answer more like "though you can, people hardly ever do" or "yes, people depend on tagged releases not in the specs repo all the time".